# eclipse kepler how to add button to connect to another form

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

I have 2 files: main_activity.xml and vision.xml. I made a button in main_activity.xml

How can I open the vision.xml using button?
Can you give me codes for MainActivity.java?

Comment: What do you use (library/framework/plugin)? What did you try?

Answer (score 0):

In your MainActivity.java add a public method as follows

```
public void startVision(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,Vision.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

then in your main_activity.xml make your Button definition look like as follow

```
<Button
    ...
    android:onClick="startVision" />
```